# Spring form doesn't work on jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am new to spring framework. I am trying to make simple crud in spring using MySQL jdbc. For datamapping I have used spring form. Whenever I try to use spring form it shows an Error
[Error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmO3Y.png)

Whenever i remove spring form and use normal form it looks ok but shows an error when used spring form. The error says **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userData' available as request attribute**

**header.jsp**

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SpringCRUDDemo</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="<c:url value='/'/>">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<c:url value='/view/'/>">View</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Update</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

**index.jsp**

```
  <%@include file="./shared/header.jsp" %>

<div class="container">
    <form:form commandName="userData" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="firstname" class="label">Enter your first name</label> 
        <form:input path="firstName"/>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

**servlet-class**

```
   @Controller

public class DefaultController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerDaoImp customerDaoImp;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("userData") Customer customer) {
        try {
            customerDaoImp.insert(customer);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewCustomer() {
        return "view-customer";
    }
}
```

Thank you ! Hoping for a good response

Comment: please try adding `<form:form action="insert"` in form and removing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form:form modelAttribute="userData">

   //rest of your form

</form:form>
```

Try this in your index.jsp instead of current version.